# Change style of most recent Tumblr post

Tags: css, themes, tumblr

Ok, I've googled this for hours with no luck.  I hope you can help and appreciate you doing so.  I am working on a grid theme for tumblr.  I want the most recent post to be formatted differently than the rest.  Namely, I want it to be full page width and have different background-color and border attributes.  In essence, creating a media header that continually updates to the most recent post.

A similar example is Digg.com.  Their top post is 3 full page width and the rest of the "top posts" are in a 3 column grid.

I am pretty competent with html and css but not with js (yet).  The site I'm working on is adventuresportlife.tumblr.com

Again, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`:nth-child(1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3anth-child) (CSS3) or [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3afirst-child) (CSS 2) pseudo-classes. In this case, for example:

```
.masonry-brick:first-child {
    background-color: red;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Your first element already has a unique ID now, with its own CSS rule from the inline style element:

```
#toppost {
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
    width: auto;
}
```

EDIT: be aware though, that CSS2 pseudo-classes are supported in IE7 and IE8, while CSS3 pseudo-classes are not (source: [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=selectors)). Since `:first-child` does the job, it might be wise to stick with that for maximum compatibility.

Comment: Wow, not as competent as I thought.  I did not know about :nth child() selector.  Great and easy solution.  Thank You!

Comment: You're welcome! I've added a bit about the compatibility of these selectors that may help too.