# Tumblr 1st post different style using nth or first child

Tags: html, css

I'd like to know exactly which element on my HTML to implement nth-child or first-child property so that the first post has a different style. A grid usually seen in many blogs. [I found this same question here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817783/change-style-of-most-recent-tumblr-post). But since my html elements are different, I can't seem to make it work. 
I tried using:

```
#content #posts:first-child {...}
```

But it doesn't work. Knowing Tumblr's limitations, I'm not sure if there's a workaround for this. Anyhow, here is my html:

```
<div id="content">
<div id="posts">

{block:Text}<!--textpost--> 
        {block:Title}
            <h1 class="title">
                <a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a>
            </h1>
        {/block:Title}
            <div class="text">{Body}</div>
        {block:More}
            <div class='rmlink'><a href="{Permalink}">Read more</a></div>
        {/block:More}
{/block:Text}<!--textpost-->

{block:Photo}<!--photopost-->
    <h1 id="ribbon">
        <a href="{Permalink}">Photo of the day</a>
    </h1>
    {LinkOpenTag}
        <div id="photopost">
            <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}"/></div>
    {LinkCloseTag}
    {block:Caption}
        <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
    {block:More}
        <div class='rmlink'>
            <a href="{Permalink}">Read more</a>
        </div>
    {/block:More}
    {/block:Caption}
{/block:Photo}<!--photopost-->




</div><!--posts-->
</div><!--content-->
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a wrapper around each post type. The usual markup I have seen is a div or article with the class post. That will allow you to target nth children. So Inside each post type block {block:Text} you need to wrap the content in a wrapper that has the same class.

Then you can write some css like this:

```
#posts .post {
  color:black;
}

#posts .post:first-child {
  color:#CCCCCC;
}
```

See my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4fsh7rvr/

The #posts element will always be an only child as it has an ID which is unique.